# windows 10 wifi keeps disconnecting when there is no internet

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

My windows 10 keeps disconnecting from wifi network as soon as the internet disconnects from the router. Is there a way to keep it connected to the network even if there is no internet in the network?

I have tried this cmd line and it didn't work, no networks where showing after i used it:

```
netsh wlan set autoconfig enable=no interface="Wi-Fi"
```

Comment: Try installing an updated Wireless driver.  Try a USB wireless NIC and see if it does the same thing,.

Comment: Are you sure it disconnects? How do you check that? Try running "ipconfig" to see if you have an IP address within said network.

Comment: hello again, I used to work on win10 ver 1809 and this problem wasn't a thing, until I started working on win10 ver 21H2, so it's not a hardware issue, I'm thinking it's an annoying feature. And for the internet, the country where I live has unstable internet connection, so it keeps on disconnecting every once in a while.

Comment: It  used to work on win10 ver 1809 .....   That was an older version of Windows 10. May be a compatibility issue. Try a newer USB card and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating the network adapter drivers, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).